# rolling back transactions but one

Tags: spring-transactions

I've got a method annotated as follows:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void x() {
   updateA();
   updateB();
   updateC();
}
```

I want all the transactions rolled back, except for the ones in updateB(). How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED, whose documentation says:
Do not support a current transaction; rather always execute non-transactionally..

```
@Transactional(propagation=PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void updateB() {
   ... 
}
```